# Integrating between phonegap and c on ubuntu platform?

Tags: ubuntu, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Is it possible to call from the phonegap JS to C or Java and opposite (not Android) on Ubuntu platform?
As I understand there is a possibility to write plugins on Android.
Is it also possible on Ubuntu?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was to use WebSockets
Natural client solution in JS and we used libwesokets
http://libwebsockets.org/trac/libwebsockets
For a server side